# How copy value of element to attribute in xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

So, I have first xml document:

```
<entries>
  <entry>
    <field>0</field>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <field>1</field>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <field>2</field>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <field>3</field>
  </entry>
</entries>
```

I'd like to transfor this documents with xsl to a new xml document. I created xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="//entries">
        <xsl:element name="entry">
            <xsl:attribute name="field">
                <xsl:copy-of select="/entries/entry/field"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'd like to get a new xml file:

```
<entries>
  <entry field="0">
  </entry>
  <entry field="1">
  </entry>
  <entry field="2">
  </entry>
  <entry field="3">
  </entry>
</entries>
```

I can't understand how  values of the elements "field" copy to attribute in elements "entry" in a new xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="/entries">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="entry">
            <entry>
                <xsl:attribute name="field">
                    <xsl:value-of select="field"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </entry>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Or shortly:

```
<xsl:template match="/entries">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="entry">
            <entry field="{field}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```